# NEXP PWA /static/chunks 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I am new to a service worker using in Nextjs, tried everything, but I have not resulted, its not catching or not updating some dynamically imported components and app crashes, this is my service-worker.js config using workbox,
I have tried self.skipWaiting(), workbox-core skipWaiting(), in next.config.js skipWaiting: true/false, dont know what to do :|:|
the error: GET status 404(Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/components_navbar_desktop_NewNavbar_js.js

can anybody help?
thanks for your attention

```
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { NetworkFirst, StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'
import { registerRoute, setCatchHandler } from 'workbox-routing'
import { matchPrecache, precacheAndRoute, cleanupOutdatedCaches } from 'workbox-precaching'

// self.skipWaiting()
clientsClaim()

// must include following lines when using inject manifest module from workbox
// https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/workbox-build#add_an_injection_point
const WB_MANIFEST = self.__WB_MANIFEST
// Precache fallback route and image
WB_MANIFEST.push(
  {
    url: '/fallback',
    revision: '1234567890'
  }
)
precacheAndRoute(WB_MANIFEST)

cleanupOutdatedCaches()
registerRoute(
  '/',
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'start-url',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 1, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
// registerRoute(
//   /^https:\/\/fonts\.(?:googleapis|gstatic)\.com\/.*/i,
//   new CacheFirst({
//     cacheName: 'google-fonts',
//     plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 4, maxAgeSeconds: 31536e3, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
//   }),
//   'GET'
// )
registerRoute(
  new RegExp('\.(eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2|font.css)$'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'fonts',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 4, maxAgeSeconds: 604800, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
// disable image cache, so we could observe the placeholder image when offline
registerRoute(
  new RegExp('\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|webp)$'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 64, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  new RegExp('\.js$'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'js',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  new RegExp('(\/sales\/\d+)'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'sale-pages',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  new RegExp('\.css$'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'styles',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)

registerRoute(
  /\.(json|xml|csv)$/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'static-data-assets',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)

registerRoute(
  /.*/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'others',
    networkTimeoutSeconds: 10,
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: true })]
  }),
  'GET'
)

  switch (event.request.destination) {
    case 'document':
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache('/fallback');
      // return caches.match('/fallback')
      break
    case 'image':
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache('/static/images/fallback.png');
      // return caches.match('/static/images/fallback.png')
      break
    case 'font':
    // If using precached URLs:
    // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
    //return caches.match('/static/fonts/fallback.otf')
    //break
    default:
      // If we don't have a fallback, just return an error response.
      return Response.error()
  }
})
```